# シェルスクリプト内でgradleを呼ぶとそれ以降の処理がなされない

Tags: shellscript, gradle

例えば以下のようなシェルスクリプト(hoge.sh)があるとします。

```
#!/bin/sh
gradle build #<- build はなくても結果は同じ
echo "hello"
```

プロンプトで

```
./hoge.sh
```

を行うと、ビルドを行い ハローといってくれます。

しかし、

```
cat hoge.sh | /bin/sh
```

を行うと、`gradle build`はBUILD SUCCESSFULと表示されるのですが、ハローまで到達せずにスクリプトが終わっている模様です。

仮に、

```
cat hoge.sh | /bin/sh -i
```

としてみますと、

```
sh-4.2$ #!/bin/sh
sh-4.2$ gradle build
..... Gradleのメッセージ
sh-4.2$ exit
```

と出ています。この`exit`のせいで`echo "hello"`が無視されているようです。

用いているGradleは3.2.1で 2.1だと同じようにしても`exit`は呼ばれずハローが帰ります。

スクリプトの2行目の`gradle build` に何か加えたり `cat hoge.sh | /bin/sh`に何かしたりするなどして`exit`を回避できないでしょうか？

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`gradle` コマンドが標準入力を開いてすぐ閉じているようで、これが原因です。
標準入力でシェルにコマンドを送り込んでいると、`gradle` 起動以降の入力を `gradle`が全部読んでしまう（読まずに閉じてしまう？）模様です。

```shell
gradle < /dev/null
echo "Hello"
```

などとして、`gradle`の標準入力に別の物を割り当てておけば大丈夫です。

（Gradle ユーザの方は `gradle`が標準入力を開いて何をしようとしているのか、確認しておいた方がよいかも知れませんが、バグっぽい挙動だなと思いました）

---

以下、最初の検証。

不思議な現象ですね。
とりあえず分かった事。

- `bash`、`zsh`、`ksh` で再現する。
  `dash`、`busybox`では再現しない。
- `gradle --no-daemon` とすると再現しない。
- シェルに`gradle`の実行前に後続行を読み込ませておけば、再現しない。

最後のは例えばこういう事です。

```
gradle; {
echo X--X
echo Y--Y
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。 まずは--no-daemonとして対処しておきます。 Unixのプロセス管理に関わってくることだと感じているのですが。。

Comment: この挙動だと、bash とかって、コマンドを読み込むためのシェルが利用している stdin と、起動されたコマンドが読み込む stdin って、同じなんですね。そして bash とかは、基本的に行単位で標準入力を消費していく、と。これはわりと他でもはまりそうですね。。

Comment: 質問文にも書きましたように、2.1, 2.4では挙動が異なるようです。どういう意図の変更なのかはわかりませんので、ひょっとするとこれからのバージョンアップでどうなるかもわかりません。　--no-daemonにすると挙動が変わるということも気になりますね。今回の件は、これから同じような問題に遭遇した時のヒントにします。大変参考になりました。ご丁寧にありがとうございます。